# php json array without index?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to creat json array from mysql db,I try to use  mysql query results to create json array object as below ,

```
$sql = "select DateTime ,Val1 from my table order by DateTime ASC ;";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$data = array();
$rowary = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
    $rowary['DateTime'] = $row['DateTime '] ;
    $rowary['Val1'] = $row['Val1 '] ;
    array_push($data,$rowary);  
  }
echo '<pre>' . var_export($data, true) . '</pre>';
```

the echo results is:

```
Array
 (
   [0] => Array
    (
        [DateTime] => 2017-02-09 12:27:23
        [Val1] => 21.0333
    )

   [1] => Array
    (
        [DateTime] => 2017-02-09 16:18:13
        [Val1] => 23.116699
    )

 )
```

but I want the results like this:

```
  Array
 (
   Array
    (
        [DateTime] => 2017-02-09 12:27:23
        [Val1] => 21.0333
    )

   Array
    (
        [DateTime] => 2017-02-09 16:18:13
        [Val1] => 23.116699
    )


 )
```

please tell me how do I do that?

Comment: It is the same thing. To access the first element you should use `print_r($data[0]);` . That would print the first array which holds `2017-02-09 12:27:23` as DateTime. The `0,1,2....` are the keys/indexes . You can't have arrays without keys.

Answer (score 2):

with Array structure there must be  way for you to access those array value, with the new one you are proposing you can't access the content, normal array is [value,value2,....,valuen] and those are indexed automatically for you as 0,1,...,n

For you, the array has inner array, which must follow the order explained above since, the parent is an array of Array=>[array1, array2,....,arrayn]

and in turn those inner array must also act like the parent array, which must take in values per slot in the data structure.

So yours won't go on well, or may be you are thinking of something else (data structure) but not array.